# Run PowerShell command in VBA

Tags: vba, powershell

I am trying to run the PowerShell command Test-Path in VBA. But I cannot get it to work. I want to check if a file exists on a remote computer or on a NAS. The DIR function does not work. Here is the VBA code that I am using.

```
Dim boolFileExists as Boolean

boolFileExists = "PowerShell -Command ""{Test-Path 'D:\Data\Exercise\Chair Workouts.docx'}"""
```

Thank you

Comment: Why using powershell in VBA for that?
Please use "Scripting.FilesystemObject" to determine whether a filesystem item exists or not.
With powershell you only get some text returned which needs to be parsed. No methods available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fileexists-method

Comment: Agree with @pwndsh. I presume VBA is going to complain if you are trying to run an outside executable.  That strikes me as a rather intolerable attack vector.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run the PowerShell command, but I was not able to get a return value. I took pwndsh's advice to use the Scripting.FilesystemObject. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right but if you want to use Powershell you need to use VBA's Shell command to do it: [PowerShell Command from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903634/powershell-command-from-vba)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to run the PowerShell command, but I was not able to get a return value. I took pwndsh's advice to use the Scripting.FilesystemObject. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much.